# Cannot find symbol with getOrDefault function of Map

Tags: java, hashmap

I have created a Hashamp of Integer type

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
```

The key for the map is an array of type Integer and I'm trying to count the occurrence of each key using the put and getOrDefault function.

Below is the code snippet for the same -

```
   static int migratoryBirds(List<Integer> arr) {
        int count = 0;
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        System.out.println(map.toString());
         for(Integer bird : arr)
          {
               System.out.println(map.getOrDefault(bird,0));
              map.put(bird,map.getOrDefault(bird,0)+1);
          }
```

I'm getting the below error while using the getOrDefault function-

```
error: cannot find symbol
               System.out.println(map.getOrDefault(bird,0));
                                     ^
  symbol:   method getOrDefault(Integer,int)
  location: variable map of type HashMap<Integer,Integer>
```

How can I resolve the error?

Comment: what's your java version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[getOrDefault](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) method was added in Java 8

> Since: 1.8

In earlier version you can use [get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)) and, if null, put a default value.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use Java-8 or a later version as `Map#getOrDefault` was introduced in Java-8. Looking at your code, I can suggest a better alternative, [`Map#merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-).

```
for(Integer bird : arr) {
    map.marge(bird, 1, Integer::sum);
}
```